# Scala update a jsobject key

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I am using play api. I want to update a key in JsObject. How can i do it. This is my code

```
import play.api.libs.json._
var sessionJson = Json.toJson(
                               Map(
                                   "sId" -> toJson(sId),
                                   "events" -> Seq(
                                                   toJson(
                                                          Map(
                                                              "eType" : toJson((eventJson \ "eType" ).as[String]),

                                                         )   
                                              )
                                    )
                               )
                    )

def reduceFunction(sessionJson1 : JsObject, sessionJson2: JsObject) = {
    var eventList = (sessionJson1 \ "events").as[Seq] ++ (sessionJson2 \ "events").as[Seq]
    println(eventList)
   //I want to do something like this
   sessionJson1['events'] = eventList
}
```

I have gone through https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaJsonTransformers but couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JsObject` is immutable, so you can't "update" it, but you could construct new object based on existing with some fields replaced.

Strangely, there is no such method on `JsObject`. `JsObject.+` doesn't check if key already exists, looks like a bug to me.

You could use `++`, it merges two objects together:

```
scala> import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json._

scala> val j = Json.obj("firstName" -> "John", "secondName" -> "Doe")
j: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"firstName":"John","secondName":"Doe"}

scala> j ++ Json.obj("firstName" -> Json.toJson("Jane"))
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"secondName":"Doe","firstName":"Jane"}
```

Or you could easily construct such function:

```
def withField[A](j: JsObject, key: String, value: A)(implicit w: Writes[A]) = 
  j ++ Json.obj(key -> value)

scala> withField(j, "firstName", "Jane")
res1: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"secondName":"Doe","firstName":"Jane"}
```